# Azure Deployment Failed

Tags: node.js, azure, github

I have a node/express site that I use GitHub / Azure for. There is also a client side .net app that is in the same repo on github, but has nothing to do with the website.

Lately all my auto-magic deployments have been failing. The log indicates that Azure is now trying to compile my client side app - and is failing on dependencies.

I do not want azure to try and compile the app - ideally I could prevent azure from even pulling it in during a deployment.

My Google-Foo is suffering as I cannot find anything meaningful on the inter-webs.

Does anyone know of a way to either

1. Prevent Azure from deploying that folder
2. Prevent Azure from trying to compile

**UPDATE**
Azure is hosting a Website for me - a NodeJs/Express website.
When I push to master on GitHub Azure sees the commit and trys to do a deployment. The deployment fails stating dependencies missing within the clientApp directory.

Comment: Additional detail on the "auto magic deployments" would be useful. E.g., is this a WebSite or a CloudService? Have you verified that you haven't added a dependency that makes your web site actually depend on the client app in some way?

Comment: @GregD I have updated with additional Detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on having a combined repo - I stripped all .NET Components out and put them in their own private repo. Azure deployments no longer fail.